# Parsing a context-free grammar in Python

Tags: python, regex, context-free-grammar

What tools are available in Python to assist in parsing a context-free grammar?

Of course it is possible to roll my own, but I am looking for a generic tool that can generate a parser for a given CFG.

Comment: Do you want to *parse the grammar* or parse input in a way defined by the grammar?

Comment: Parse input defined by the grammar, sorry I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I warmly recommend [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) - it's a Lex/Yacc clone in Python that uses the language's introspection facilities in a sophisticated manner to allow for a very natural specification of the grammar. Yacc, if you recall, is the very embodiment of CFGs in an understandable DSL that defines how one parses them.

I used it to implement my [parser for ANSI C](http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/) and the interaction with PLY was almost effortless.