# python split and evaluate

Tags: python, string, split

How might I split a string (with postfix) into one with parentheses? What I mean is, if the user inputs `3 (3 6 *) *` I want the interpreter to be able to multiply `3 18 *` and understand the parentheses in the text. Is this possible? Like a `str.split()` but with a start and end delimiter?

Am I not being realistic? I found the `shlex` module similar, but it only does quotes AFAIK.

Comment: Regarding the quality standards: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards. In particular, make sure to use correct capitalisation.

Comment: Why are you bothering to use parentheses in a postfix expression?

Comment: Why do postfix expressions need parentheses?

Comment: those are very good questions, but i'm just curious.

Comment: and please answer if you can...the `postfix` part is kind of irrelevant

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you want as a result from the "split" operation? What would be the result of applying it to `3 (3 (2 4 +) *) *`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using `re` is such a bad idea. You could just go through replacing the nested parenthesis one at a time with the result of their operation. Seems pretty straight forward to me:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\([^\(\)]+\)')

def eval_expr(expr):
    match = regex.search(expr)
    if match:
        sub_expr = match.group()
        return eval_expr(expr.replace(sub_expr, str(eval_expr(sub_expr[1:-1]))))
    args = expr.split()
    op = args.pop()
    return eval(op.join(args))
```

And use like so:

```
>>> eval_expr('(1 (2 3 -) 4 +) (5 6 *) 7 +')
<<< 41
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not very familiar with regular expressions. Would it be too much to ask to ask for an example for this one?

As Chris's, uh, variegated comments indicated, you can't have an (true) regular expression that will parse nested parentheses.  (According to him, there are some sort of hacks and extensions that would broaden the expression-language to let it parse context-free grammars.  This is the first I've heard of that, but it sounds like a bad idea to me.)

> This answer also seems to have downvotes...Are there any other ways to do this?

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979703/parsing-a-context-free-grammar-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to extract parenthesized subexpressions. [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) may be helpful if what you care about is splitting on matched parentheses. A straightforward regular expression would let you pick out the subexpressions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
source = r"3 (3 6 *) *"
rewritten = source[:]
match_index = 1
snag_deepest = re.compile(r"""(?P<pre>.*)(?P<sub>\([^()]+\))(?P<post>.*)""")

print "Starting -> %s" % (rewritten)
results = snag_deepest.search(rewritten)
while results is not None:
    print "Subexpression %d -> %s" % (match_index, results.group('sub'))
    rewritten = "%s%s%s" % (results.group('pre'), "sub_%d" % match_index, results.group('post'))
    print "Rewritten as -> %s" % (rewritten)
    results = snag_deepest.search(rewritten)
    match_index += 1
```

produces

```
Starting -> 3 (3 6 *) *
Subexpression 1 -> (3 6 *)
Rewritten as -> 3 sub_1 *
```

Comment: No you can't! I can't hear you! LALALALALALALA!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with regular expressions. Would it be too much to ask to ask for an example for this one?

Comment: This answer also seems to have downvotes...Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: I would bet a reasonable sum of money that you are wrong.  Regular expressions parse regular grammars and what the OP is describing is (I believe) a context-free grammar.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Well-formed_parentheses) even says “The canonical example of a context free grammar is parenthesis matching.”

Comment: @Malvolio - Indeed you are correct. Modern regex flavors often _can_ evaluate congext-free grammars, however the syntax to do so is increasingly complex and many (such as myself) discourage its use at all.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I would like to do?

Comment: @tekknolagi You can extract parenthesized expressions, but as @Chris Lutz notes it's complicated. What I did was write a simple expression to iteratively grab a parenthesized expression with no subexpression. To write a single expression would be nasty.

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that parenthesis are not necessary in postfix notation when the [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of an operator is known. To see why:

```
3 3 6 * *
```

Starting from the left, stack operands until you encounter an operator:

```
operands <- 3 <- 3 <- 6
operator: *
```

We know that `*` is a binary operator, so pop two operands off the stack, apply the operator, and push the result back on:

```
operands -> 3 -> 6
operands <- 18
```

Continue to accumulate operands until you encounter another operator:

```
operator: *
operands -> 3 -> 18
operands <- 54
```

When the expression is consumed (assuming it's well-formed) the stack will contain one value: the result.

But your question is about parenthesis: assuming that your desire is to be able to parse arbitrarily *nested* parentheses, regular expressions will not help you, for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns). You need something that can recognize a [context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), i.e. a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton).

But you're looking, I take it, for something more than abstract computer science-speak; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582398/writing-a-simple-equation-parser)'s a related question that has some useful information on the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm), which converts parenthesized infix expressions into postfix expressions.

**Edit**: Ok, I should have said "*true* regular expressions *alone* will not help you." You could use regular expressions (matching innermost pairs of parenthesis) and substitution to (in effect) treat a parenthesized expression as its own implicit parse tree. But the Shunting Yard Algorithm is cooler :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong but your expression is the RPD. If so there is no actual need to use parenthesis. Please find my sample(not optimized and weird) below:

```
import operator

def rpd_eval(expression):
    if expression.count('(') != expression.count(')'):
        return 0    
    expression = expression.replace(' ', '')
    ops = {'*': operator.mul, '**': operator.pow, '%': operator.mod,
           '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '/': operator.div,
           '^': operator.pow}        
    res = []
    for v in list(expression):
        if not v in ops and v not in ['(',')']:
            res.append(int(v))
        elif v not in ['(',')']:
            b = float(res.pop())
            a = float(res.pop())
            res.append(ops[v](a, b))
    return res[0]

print rpd_eval('3(63*)*5+') # will print 59
```